FilteredRelation with OuterRef not working after updating to Django 5
After updating to Django 5, I have the same problem described in this post: How to use FilteredRelation with OuterRef?
My queryset looks as follows:
ModelA.objects.annotate(
   model_b_objects_count=SubqueryCount(
      ModelB.objects.filter(
         model_a_id=OuterRef('id')
      ).annotate(
         outer_user_id=OuterRef('user_id'), # user_id within ModelA
         model_c_relation=FilteredRelation('model_c_objects', condition=Q(model_c_objects__user_id=F('outer_user_id')
      )
   )
)

While using Django 4.1, it was working fine, since trying to update, I get the error
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
Anyone know how to fix this or is it sth that Django has to fix?
I tried the solution provided in the mentioned post, but still got the same error.
